# top.window.close() stops working on Google Editor add-on after Chrome 88 update

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-apps-script, google-sheets, dom-events

We are using Google Outh2 client provided for google App-script [Google-outhClient2](https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2) for Authorizing access to our Server.
The library opens the Authorization URL in the next tab and after successful login, it would close the tab with the custom function written by us

```
setTimeout(function() { top.window.close() }, 1);
```

However, after the recent Chrome update to 88, the above method has stopped working.
This is the message I receive

> "Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by them"

When I read about Chrome 88 changes, I came across Google's policy change on "Tab Hopping"

Any other insight on how to tackle this would be helpful.

Updated the code workflow here

```
function getDriveService() {
try {
 return OAuth2.createService(‘service’)       
      .setAuthorizationBaseUrl(authUrl)
      .setTokenUrl(tokenUrl)
      .setRefreshUrl(tokenUrl)
      .setClientId(Client ID)
      .setClientSecret(Client Secret)
      .setCallbackFunction('authCallback')
      .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties())
      .setScope('user')
      .setExpirationMinutes(0)
      .setParam('access_type', 'offline')
     .setParam('prompt', 'consent')
    } 
    catch(e) {
     
    }
}


function authCallback(request) {
  try {
  var driveService = getDriveService();
  var isAuthorized = driveService.handleCallback(request);
  if (isAuthorized) {
    showFile();
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Success! <script>setTimeout(function() { top.window.close() }, 1);</script>');
  } else {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Denied. You can close this tab');
  }
} 
catch(e) {
}
}
```

Comment: Can you provide [mcve]?

Comment: Hi @Cooper, If you see the link provided above, it has the details how the library has implemented the same. 
There is a call back function where I have written the above code. 
When I open the developer tool console, I see the control is with the iFrame and ideally it worked perfectly since the chrome 88 update.
Please let me know if there is anything else thats needed

Comment: Hi ! Is this only happenning to you with Editor Add-Ons? Also, could you please share the code for the authorization process in Apps Script that opens the window (**without providing any sensitive data**) so that we can test it in our own environment as acurrately as your script? Thanks !

Comment: Hi, 
To answer the question, it happens through the editor add-on. I tried the same from the "box" GWA from Market place and the issue isn't present.
Pasting the code in the next comment

Comment: OAuth2.createService('Service')
      .setAuthorizationBaseUrl(authUrl)
      .setTokenUrl(tokenUrl)
      .setRefreshUrl(tokenUrl)
      .setClientId(clientID)
      .setClientSecret(clientSecret)
      .setCallbackFunction('authCallback')
      .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties())
      .setScope('user')
      .setExpirationMinutes(0)
      .setParam('access_type', 'offline')
      .setParam('prompt', 'consent')

Comment: Hi ! Thank you for answering. What is this editor Add-On for (Google Sheets, Google Docs, etc)? If you could also edit your question to provide a minimal reproducible example of your Add-On code it could be helpful for me to try to reproduce your issue as accuratelly as possible. Thanks !

Comment: Hi @MateoRandwolf, The code is present on all the three editors. 
Basically I am trying to login to our company server from the add-on. While I am logging into our server using the outh2 client, initially it closed the tab and directed us back to our add-on. Now the routing has stopped. 
This works perfectly fine on a google workspace addon for editors. 
I will add the code and the flow what I follow. 
Thanks!

Comment: Hi ! Thank you for providing further code. The code seems to be fine, can you also reproduce this in a different browser such as Firefox? Does it work well in other browsers and different Chrome versions ?

Comment: Hello @MateoRandwolf, Sorry for the delayed response. 
The top.window.close() stopped working from Chrome 88 and it is not working in firefox 84.

Comment: Hi @MateoRandwolf, Any update on this?